# Effect of changing reference on R squard in logistic regression

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression

In Logistic regression, say with 3 dummy variables, what will be the effect on R squared value if say you change the reference from one dummy variable to another one. does R squared stay the same?

Comment: Why not test it and see?

Comment: But how do you get an r squared from a logistic regression at all?

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about R-squared for the model, then it should be the same.

To test it, you will need to change the reference for the factorial variables.

```
Variable <- relevel(Variable,ref=...)
```

Then run your model again and get the summary.

But I don't understand why you would prefer r-squared for logistic regression. In general, if you want to compare two models, you want to check for the AIC/BIC. If you want to see the contribution of each variable, you want to check for their ORs.

Good luck.